# SVG , пересечение элементов

Tags: javascript, svg, snapsvg

Доброе время суток . Рисую svg , используя snap.js. Элементы создаются циклом и каждому новому элементу координаты задаются рандомно ( в пределе возможного ), проблема заключается : Как реализовать что бы новые элементы НЕ появлялись друг на друге , то есть между элементами всегда было расстояние ?

```
var a = Snap(1500,800);
let randX = randomInteger(50,250);
let randY = randomInteger(50,250);
var circle = a.circle(randX, randY, 30).attr(style);
```